# Google maps V3 GSize has changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am switching google maps from v2 to v3 and I am running into a problem with finding the conversion from GSize. Does anyone know how to make the change.

```
opts = {
    'labelText': infoname,
    'labelClass': 'citymarkers',
    'labelOffset': new GSize(-35, -40)
};

var marker = new LabeledMarker( 
    new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng), 
    opts);

this.labelOffset = options.labelOffset || new GSize(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`LabeledMarker`](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/) class you are using is a [third-party extension](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/) and not part of the Google Maps API.

There is a [utility library for the v3 API](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) similar to the [v2 version](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/), and there is an extension called [`MarkerWithLabel`](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). You may want to try that instead.

You may also be interested in checking out the following article for an alternative v3 solution:

- [Label overlay example for Google Maps API v3](http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html) by Marc Ridey

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the [Size](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Size) class instead.

Comment: I tried using 

'labelOffset': new Size(-35, -40) but i got this error
Size is not defined

Comment: @Matt: You would have to use `google.maps.Size` but I think it still won't work, since `LabeledMarker` is an extension for the v2 API.